# How to put QR code into pdf file?

Tags: php, pdf, yii2, qr-code

how can I generate and put my QR code into a pdf file?? Theres a code that generates a pdf:

```
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
</head>
<body class="pdf">
    <table class="table-label <?=$size?>">
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($labelFields as $key=>$value) { ?>
                <tr class="<?='row'.strtolower($key)?>">
                    <th><?=is_numeric($key)?$key+1:$key?></th><td><?=$value?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Code above returns a pdf which looks like that:

[generated_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOsZR.png)

I want to create a QR code and put all parameters from table to it. I've tried to do this like:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;
?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>"/>
</head>
<body class="pdf">
    <table class="table-label <?=$size?>">
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($labelFields as $key=>$value) { ?>
                <tr class="<?='row'.strtolower($key)?>">
                <?php /* klucz => wartosc; poniewaz klucz idzie od 0 zwieksz o 1 */ ?>
                    <th><?=is_numeric($key)?$key+1:$key?></th><td><?=$value?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }
                $qrcode = new QRcode("dsfdfddsdsdsdfsdfsdfsdfs");
                //echo $qrcode->writeString();die();
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th><?='Kod QR'?></th><td><?=$qrcode->writeString()?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Unfortunately after those changes i receive error

**PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**

Regards

Comment: HTML is not a png...

Comment: You could use `$qrCode->writeFile(__DIR__.'/qrcode.png');` then use a standard <img> tag to show it. `qrcode.png` would obviously need to be unique.

Comment: You could also base64(data URI) its string and use that instead of needing to save it.

Comment: When I use `<th><?='Kod QR'?></th><td><?='<img src"' . $qrCode->writeDataUri() . '">'?></td>` nothing happens, but `<th><?='Kod QR'?></th><td><?=$qrCode->writeDataUri()?></td>` returns a long base64 data url.

Comment: use `src="` not `src"`, nice find on `writeDataUri` didnt see that.

Comment: Oh, what a trivial mistake. Works perfectfly now ;). Thank You alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<th><?='Kod QR'?></th><td><?=$qrCode->writeDataUri()?></td>
```

This is solution to my problem.